# Strong types in Protocol Buffers

Tags: design-patterns, protocol-buffers, strong-typing

Since protobuf has no support for type alias is it a valid approach to create a strong type using a message with a single `value` member like the following?

```
message ID {
    uint32 value = 1;
}
message Entity {
    ID id = 1;
    uint32 count = 2;
}
```

Or is it better to use just the scalar:

```
message Entity {
    uint32 id = 1;
    uint32 count = 2;
}
```

The strong type makes in my opinion the code more readable and has the benefit that in the case I want to change the id from uint32 to uint64 I would only have to change one line. Since I haven't seen this online, I wondered if there is any drawback.

Answer (score 1):

There is some minor drawback for the developer, in that they have to refer to `entity.id.value` instead of just `entity.id`. Whether or not the strong type ends up paying off or causes more problems than it solves will, I think, come down to the individual circumstances of the project.

However, it is worth exploring where the strong type approach might go. For example, consider a message field that is supposed to be a bearing, valid between 0 and 359. If you had a `Bearing` type, then you've got some consistency of how bearing values are implemented in the application source code. You can then more readily check (through code review) that everywhere `Bearing` is used, it is also checked for validity. The code review is helped because you can simply search for all variables declared `Bearing`, and check what is done with them.

Whereas without the strong type approach, bearing values might be called all manner of things such as `bearing`, `brng`, `angle`, `heading`, etc, and it then takes more than a simple search to track down all places where bearing values are being used.

This though exposes one of the big weaknesses of Google Protocol Buffers, in that there is no way to define validity constraints in the schema other than in a comment and review source code to see that the comment has been actioned in the application source code. Whereas, something like ASN.1 schema (which aren't so very different at a basic level to GPB schema) does allow formal expression of validity constraints, and the generated code will automatically enforce them for you at serialisation / deserialisation. This is a big time saver.

Comment: "_there is no way to define validity constraints in the schema other than in a comment_" - There's a workaround, by extending protobuf.FieldOptions and using reflection to validate at runtime.  The syntax we use would look like: `int32 bearing = 1 [(check.values) = { min: 0, max: 359 }];`

Comment: @AlexO, that's reaching into areas of syntax with which I'm unfamiliar! Interesting that there's an option to do at least that. It's not the ideal where the generated code does the validation with no need for the dev(s) to write anything. However, once written at least such code would pick up on any changes in the .proto file. When you exploit ASN.1's constraints to the full, they're very useful, especially if expressed in terms of Value declarations, and when using compact binary encodings like uPER. Hopefully one day Google will adopt something similar.

Comment: The syntax is one that we came up with and is by no means standard, though it is based on extensions of `protobuf.FieldOptions`. It is also a bit kludgy since it requires us to pass the message to a custom-made validation function (which was a bother to write and debug), but it is better than nothing :)

Comment: @AlexO You may wish to take a look at https://github.com/bufbuild/protoc-gen-validate/blob/main/README.md. I've been glancing at that for a while, and I notice now that they claim it's stable. It adds validation to generated code, derived from constraints expressed in schema. Works for Go, Java, Python, and C++ a bit. Really it'd be better if Google added to the specification, rather than independent projects "make do". But, good work none the less!